# How does z-index affect tab order?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

this is my first question, so sorry if I've not done something correctly.

I can find nothing on the internet regarding this topic:

When I create a new wpf app with the following Grid, tab order is as expected (first textbox, down):

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,160,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
</Grid>
```

If I set `Panel.ZIndex` on one of them, it can affect the tab index in different ways (depending on which one). This one is the most notable, since it seems to reverse the tab order:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,160,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="95,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
</Grid>
```

So how does this work? Does zindex really affect the tab order, or does it somehow create a new tab group to hold the controls with the same zindex? Is there a way to stop this so zindex has no impact at all?

I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve hard coding the tab order using the `TabIndex` property. Ideally there would be some way to prevent the zindex interfering

Comment: Just to make sure, by "hard coding the tab order" you mean using the `TabIndex` property right?

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not set the _TabIndex_es, *ZIndex* matters. This is because KeyboardNavigation uses [VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the next child (See GetNextSibling(...) in [KeyboardNavigation source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/NetFXw7/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Input/KeyboardNavigation@cs/1/KeyboardNavigation@cs)) and this method returns visuals with lower _ZIndex_es first. If you hard code the TabIndex everything is as expected.